# Stepping over one method in the debugger but continuing normal debugging after

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 with .NET 4.6.1

I have some user code that calls an infrastructure code (non user code, but code made to facilitate the application) and the infrastructure code calls user code and continues the execution. So:
usercode1 -> infrastructure method -> usercode2

In debugging, I want to step over the infrastructure method only but I want to continue in the usercode2 without debugging through the internals of the infrastructure method.

I tried using `DebuggerStepThrough` and `DebuggerNonUserCode` attributes on the infrastructure method but they seem to step over usercode2 unless if I have a break point there.

Any recommendations of how to step over the infrastructure code only and continue debugging into the usercode2?

Answer (score 0):

[have you tried setting a break point at the section you want to start debugging?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGmAM.png)

Check out :[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDabuT-JDXE) tutorial if you are unsure on how to do it

Comment: I am not having a problem debugging, I want to step over a method even if I hit step in.

Comment: This is the flow of your code usercode1 -> infrastructure method -> usercode2. what you need to have is the following

Breakpoint @usercode1 -> infrastructure method -> Breakpoint @ usercode2.

Once youe've reached the end of usercode1 you can continue(F5) to the next break point

Comment: As in most businesses social sites are usually blocked and following SO guides, could you please write the solution here.

Comment: Added an image as an example

Comment: I am already doing a break point as I mentioned "unless if I have a break point there" but this is not what I am looking for because I usually don't know which usercode2 is going to load, I just want to continue debugging to whatever code is loaded.

Comment: In that case the put a break point at the end of the infrastructure code and just stepin to the usercode 2

Comment: But I don't want to step into the infrastructure code. I am not sure that you are trying to solve this particular specific case that I described in the request.